# Exception while converting "JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject error"

Tags: java, android, json

I have that JSON Response

```
           {"as_of":"2013-04-22T19:50:41Z","trends":[{"events":null,
            "query":"%23RhymeATweepsName","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?
            q=%23RhymeATweepsName","promoted_content":null,
            "name":"#RhymeATweepsName"},                
            {"events":null,"query":"%23EarthDayPK","url":
            "http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?
            =%23EarthDayPK","promoted_content":null,"name":
            "#EarthDayPK"}],"locations":
            [{"woeid":*******,"name":"********"}],"created_at":"2013-04-22T19:38:16Z"}
```

and i am parsing it with the following code

```
             jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject post = null;
                for (int ii = 0; ii < jArray.length(); ii++) {
                    post = jArray.getJSONObject(ii);
                     String name = post.getJSONObject("trends").getString("name") + "\n";
                }
            }
```

But it throwing Exception "JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject error"

Comment: ``trends`` is an array as the exception states.

Comment: yes it is. Solution ?

Comment: @ExtremeProgrammer I guess there's a `getJSONArray` method somewhere close the `getJSONObject` method?

Answer (score 4):

As seen in your JSON, `trends` is not a `JSONObject`, but a `JSONArray`:

```
"trends":[
    {
        "events":null,
        "query":"%23RhymeATweepsName",
        "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search? q=%23RhymeATweepsName",
        "promoted_content":null,
        "name":"#RhymeATweepsName"
    },
    {
        "events":null,
        "query":"%23EarthDayPK",
        "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search? =%23EarthDayPK",
        "promoted_content":null,
        "name":"#EarthDayPK"
    }
]
```

You should parse it pretty much like this:

```
String name = post.getJSONArray("trends").getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
//                                        or iterate... ^^
```

Comment: O yes, then how to parse that ?

Comment: You would just have to read the trends as an array, `trends = JSONArray("trends")` and then iterate through them.

Comment: YUP, Got it Thanks for Quick response :Highly Appreciated: